# How can i inherit instance parameters /methods from another class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object

i have the following class:

```
class Config: 
    
def __init__(self,config_file='model.yml'):
    abs_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    project_path = os.path.join(abs_path,'..')
    config_folder = os.path.join(project_path,'model_configs')
    print(os.path.join(config_folder,config_file))
    try: 
        with open(os.path.join(config_folder,config_file),'r') as cfg_file:
            self.config = yaml.load(cfg_file)
    except FileNotFoundError as fe: 
        print("config not found")
        sys.exit(2)
    
    self.EXTRACTION = self.config['data_extraction']
    self.TRAINING = self.config['model_build']
```

i then make a another class in a different py file:

```
from config.config_read import Config as config

class Model1():

 def __init__(self, config):
     self.extraction = config.EXTRACTION


 def extract():



    return(df)
```

How can i inherit the self.EXTRACTION and self.TRAINING from the config class and read these variables into Model1 ? If i try this in a notebook:

```
from config.config_read import Config as config

    class Model1(config):
    
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.extraction = config.EXTRACTION

e = Model1()
e.extraction
```

doesn't return me what i want? Rather newish to this...

Comment: You need an *instance* of `Config`, not the class itself.

Comment: tried doing that didnt work, if you could be clearer would appreciate

Comment: What exactly did you try? It's not clear you need inheritance here at all. `e = Model1(config())` doesn't require `Model1` to *inherit* from `config`.

Comment: pls see edit, i have changed it but it does not work

Comment: You aren't passing the required argument to `Model1`, and `Config` doesn't have a *class* attribute named `extraction`.

Comment: what i am trying to do is pass the instance variables through to the class.

Answer (score 1):

`Config` is a class; *instances* of `Config` have the `extraction` attribute.

```
from config.config_read import Config

class Model1():

    def __init__(self, config):
        self.extraction = config.EXTRACTION

e = Model1(Config())
e.extraction
```